# Centrar divs, y hacer que sean responsive

Tags: html, css, css3

Quiero que los divs estén de acuerdo al diseño de las imágenes, en cualquier dispositivo, no he logrado que desde una pantalla pequeña, el div "info-card" se posicione debajo de la foto.

y adicional que todo esté alineado en el centro, dependiendo del dispositivo, hasta el momento se muestra la estructura pero faltan esos detalles que no he logrado resolver.
No se si sea necesario colocar la tabla dentro del div, o si lo pueda hacer de otra manera.
Gracias.

```css
.profile-card{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .title-card{
    
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#1f212b;
    padding:5px 0px;

    }
    .image-card{
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    background:#CC6600;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    .info-card{
    width:45%;
    float:left;
    background:#000FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="profile-card">
        <div class="title-card">
            <h2 class="name-card">name <span clas="lastname-card">lastname</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="image-card">
            <img class="image-profile"src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sq-sample10.jpg" alt="sample10" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-card">
        <table class="" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Building:</td>
                <td>IP-304</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telephone number</td>
                <td>4546456</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Web site</td>
                <td><a href="">href</a> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>asas@correo.cm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Opening hours</td>
                <td>Previous appointment</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        </div>
        <div class="research-card">
    <h2 class="title-card">Academic degrees</h2>
        <ul class="list-card">
                <li>lista</li>
                <li>lista</li>
                <li>list</li>
             <h2 class="title-card">Research area</h2>
                <li>lista</li>
            <h2 class="title-card">Other research interests</h2>
                <li>lista</li>

             <h2 class="title-card">Current teaching assignment</h2>
                <li>lista</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[[image: Diseño que quiero[1]][image: Responsive]

Comment: Yo te recomendaría no trabajar con tablas para hacer tu sitio responsive. Aparte de eso no me queda del todo claro qué es lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Hola Jheyman, gracias por responder.

Comment: Hola Jheyman, gracias por responder. Quiero lograr una estructura como la de las imágenes, la primer imagen es la vista para PC's, donde esta el titulo, luego en la segunda linea va la foto y una lista; la tercer linea va otro texto, he logrado mantener esa estructura para PC, pero cuando la veo desde un dispositivo movil, no se hace responsive. POr favor revisa las imagenes y me cuentas. Gracias

Comment: Toma, estudia: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_responsive.htm te ayudará mucho :)

Comment: Gracias fredyfx, voy a consultar mas.

Comment: @JairBonilla añade una imagen de cómo lo ves actualmente en vistas móviles

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir `@media` para cada breakpoint que quieras dar a tu `responsive`. En cada una de esas medias necesitas redimensionar los `divs` o `tables` que tengas, en el caso de la menor de ellas, para pantallas smartphone por ejemplo tendría que ser algo así:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .image-card{
    width:100%;
    }
    .info-card{
    width:100%;
    }
    .research-card{
    width:100%;
    }
}
```

Además tienes mal colocados los elementos de tu código si deseas colocarlos como muestras en las imágenes. Deberías pasar la imagen como `background` al `div` que la contiene con un tamaño preestablecido del mismo o redimensionar tu imagen para que se ajuste como quieres al tamaño en concreto que deseas. El `research-card` debe tener también un ancho fijo y un `display: block`:

```
.research-card{
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo trabajar con grid, así mantendrás tu página mas ordenada y podrás manipular mejor los elementos. Por cierto, añadiste los meta tags? Son necesarios si quieres hacer tu página responsive.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Si no logras resolverlo con eso, intenta usar media queries para cambiar las propiedades de los elementos.

Comment: Hola Diego, gracias por responder, si están los meta tags tal cual los mencionas. He realizado pruebas sin nada de contenido, es decir, solo con divs, y funciona, pero por alguna razon, cuando le agrego el texto deja de funcionar.

Comment: Intenta entonces usar media queries, así cuando entres al formato móvil(menos de 800px) los elementos tomen el formato que quieres.